# Deploying ASP.NET MVC Internet application with MySQL on Apache/mod_mono

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, apache, mono

First off, I'm pretty new to all this stuff.

I use my Windows machine with Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate as development environment and want to host the created web application on a Linux machine using Apache/mod_mono.

The Linux machine runs:

- CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
- Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) with mod_mono
- Mono JIT compiler version 3.10.0 (tarball Sat Oct  4 16:22:21 UTC 2014)

I'm currently hosting 2 ASP.NET applications on the Linux machine:

1. **monotest**: an MVC project created with a MonoDevelop template mainly to test the apache configuration. This application works fine (even though the log throws errors when restarting apache)
2. **webappexample**: an MVC3 project with razor views and MySQL database created with the Visual Studio template. This website gives a '500 Internal Server Error'.

When I restart Apache, this output is printed in the error_log:

```
[Tue Nov 04 11:03:30 2014] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
mod-mono-server received a shutdown message
Missing method System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler::Create(object,object,XmlNode) in assembly /opt/mono/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll, referenced in assembly /opt/mono/lib/mono/gac/System.Configuration/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
Missing method System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler::Create(object,object,XmlNode) in assembly /opt/mono/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll, referenced in assembly /opt/mono/lib/mono/gac/System.Configuration/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
Missing method System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager::get_AppSettings() in assembly /var/www/html/webappexample/bin/System.Configuration.dll, referenced in assembly /opt/mono/lib/mono/gac/Mono.WebServer2/0.4.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.WebServer2.dll
mod-mono-server received a shutdown message
[Tue Nov 04 11:03:31 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Nov 04 11:03:31 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Nov 04 11:03:32 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_mono/2.11 PHP/5.4.32 configured -- resuming normal operations
mod-mono-server4
mod-mono-server4
mod-mono-server4
Listening on: /tmp/mod_mono_server_monotest
Root directory: /var/www/html/mono_test
Exception caught during reading the configuration file:
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler.Create'.
  at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection (System.String configKey) [0x0000d] in /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/mono-3.10.0/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/ClientConfigurationSystem.cs:62
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection (System.String sectionName) [0x00000] in /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/mono-3.10.0/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/ConfigurationManager.cs:159
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings () [0x00000] in /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/mono-3.10.0/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/ConfigurationManager.cs:173
  at Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server.get_AppSettings () [0x00001] in /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/xsp-1368532016/src/Mono.WebServer.Apache/main.cs:213
  at Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server+ApplicationSettings..ctor () [0x0002b] in /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/xsp-1368532016/src/Mono.WebServer.Apache/main.cs:63
mod-mono-server4
Listening on: /tmp/mod_mono_server_webappexample
Root directory: /var/www/html/webappexample
```

And when I visit the webappexample, this is in the error_log:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Mono.WebServer.BaseApplicationHost.EndOfRequest (Mono.WebServer.MonoWorkerRequest mwr) [0x0002b] in /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/xsp-1368532016/src/Mono.WebServer/BaseApplicationHost.cs:141
  at Mono.WebServer.ModMonoApplicationHost.ProcessRequest (Int32 reqId, System.String verb, System.String queryString, System.String path, System.String protocol, System.String localAddress, Int32 serverPort, System.String remoteAddress, Int32 remotePort, System.String remoteName, System.String[] headers, System.String[] headerValues, System.Object worker) [0x00175] in /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/xsp-1368532016/src/Mono.WebServer.Apache/ModMonoApplicationHost.cs:109
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.WebServer.ModMonoApplicationHost:ProcessRequest (int,string,string,string,string,string,int,string,int,string,string[],string[],object)
  at Mono.WebServer.ModMonoWorker.InnerRun (System.Object state) [0x002a7] in /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/xsp-1368532016/src/Mono.WebServer.Apache/ModMonoWorker.cs:253
  at Mono.WebServer.ModMonoWorker.Run (System.Object state) [0x00004] in /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/xsp-1368532016/src/Mono.WebServer.Apache/ModMonoWorker.cs:92
[Tue Nov 04 11:37:55 2014] [error] (70014)End of file found: read_data failed
[Tue Nov 04 11:37:55 2014] [error] Command stream corrupted, last command was -1
```

After some googling, I've came across quite a few blog posts about copying certain DLLs.. I've lost track of what I've tried so far but nothing solved my problem yet. I've also tried compiling webappexample with the mono compiler, this compiles without any warnings/errors but still doesn't solve my problem.

Can anyone provide some insights or solutions here?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the configuration of mod_mono in your linux box? Maybe mond_mono is configured to use the aspnet v2 framework (.net v2, v3, v3.5) and perhaps your app needs the v4 framework (.net v4, v4.5)

I cant access a linux box right now but i believe that conf file is under /mods-available/mod-mono.conf
That file should have either a reference to version 2 or 4 of the mod-mono

I think that you should also check the configuration of your apache site /sites-available/.conf I believe this conf file has also some mod_mono references which should be pointing to the right version.